# Is it possible to return a row from a table as DML (insert, update) in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to generate an insert statement from a row in a table?

if the row is [1 , "myfirstname", "mylastname"] is there a way of getting a query like:

"insert into table sometable (uid, FirstName, LastName) values (1 , "myfirstname",
"mylastname")

...without using dynamic sql?

Thanks

EDIT:

admittedly, i am lazy about this and was trying not to use dynamic sql / all_tab_columns.
I was hoping for some magical function call that returns a DML statement for a row just as there is a way to get a DDL expression for an object:

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TABLENAME') from dual ... but DML for a row ... it's too much to ask i think.

Comment: you mean you want to insert values that you get from a select?

Comment: insert into sometable(uid, firstname, lastname) select uid, first, last from someOtherTable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to turn "raw" data into a SQL insert statement.

There is no way to do this with SQL, but usually GUI clients have this kind of functionality

Comment: the internet seems to agree with you on this one, i'll have whip up something ugly using dynamic sql.  thanks

Comment: assuming his string has known format - you can do a workaround. check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
   insert into table sometable (uid, FirstName, LastName) SELECT 1 ,'myfirstname', 'mylastname' from othertable where somecondition
```

Take a look at [this](http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html) also

Comment: yeah but that would require me to type all the field values which is the exact opposite of what i am trying to accomplish. Assume that you dont know the column names or their types. thanks for the try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

select 'insert into tablename (fieldname) values(''' + a.fieldname + ''')' from table a

Format each field value as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string format is more or less static you might want to play with this sample:

```
INSERT
   INTO
  someTable
  (
     SELECT
      regexp_substr(expr, '[0-9]+') val1   ,
      regexp_substr(expr, '[a-zA-Z]+') val2,
      regexp_substr(expr, '[a-zA-Z]+', 1, 2) val3
       FROM
      (
         SELECT
          '[1 , "myfirstname", "mylastname"]' expr
           FROM
          dual
      )
  ) ;
```

Comment: Nice idea. But although it technically achieves the same effect, I don't think this is what LoudNPossiblyWrong was looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

download SQLDeveloper from Oracle website (it's free). 
Log into your database schema, and from the list of Tables, right click on the table you want to get data from, choose "Export..." and then follow the wizard steps, chosing the format "Insert" for your data.  It'll create you a file of insert statements for the data in your table.
You can restrict it to just a subset of rows by supplying where-clause conditions in one step in the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in Oracle Sqldeveloper.
Its easy as CMG told in the post.
Just right click on the table you want to get the datas-->Export-->INSERT-->specify file path to save the scripts-->bingo  :)